# Open/LibreSwan Networkmanager Plugin

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, network-manager, vpn

When trying to Create an Openswan connection in networkmanager, it cannot connect due to a missing plugin.

an apt search shows that openswan is using libreswan but for neither name I can find a networkmanager plugin as a package. does the package have an obscure name or is it just no longer available?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome` ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup

Comment: does not work, I would assume because IPSec/IKEv2 is not the same as L2TP. and no strongswan is not an option because strongswan does not seem to support PSK

Comment: `apt show network-manager-l2tp` "with optional IPsec support." If I do `apt search network-manager ikev2` I see `network-manager-strongswan` and `strongswan-nm` . You can look at the list of swan packages available at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=swan

Comment: yes I saw strongswan but strongswan only does Certificates, Smartcards or EAP, I need PSK

Answer (score 1):

VPN [network-manager-libreswan](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-libreswan) was never ported to Debian/Ubuntu. It changed its name from NetworkManager-openswan to NetworkManager-libreswan with version 1.2, but is still compatible with openswan.

If you need an IPsec IKEv2 with PSK VPN connection, I think the only solution is to build NetworkManager-libreswan from source code as NetworkManager-strongswan doesn't support PSK.

If you were trying to do an IPsec IKEv1 Xauth (Cisco-style) VPN connection which neither network-manager-l2tp nor network-manager-strongswan can do, you could try [network-manager-vpnc](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-vpnc) which does Cisco-style IPsec IKEv1 Xauth VPN connections.